# Doing something at a certain point in an array Flash AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I am making a Rhythm game and I am looking to change the time when the song reaches a certain point; but I do not know how to do this.

This is my array controlling what note is being played `(1=Z,2=X,3=N,4=M)`:

```
var lvlArray1:Array = new Array(0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,
                                3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,1,4,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

And to control my tempo I have:

```
//sTempo is how many frames it takes before
//a note is created. Because it's 12, and
//the frame rate is 24, it will take a half of a second
//for a note to be made
var sTempo:Number = 12;
```

How would I go about changing the tempo to say 6 when the 40th note is played (where the `1,4,1,4` starts)

I feel like this might be something incredibly simple, but my mind is just blank.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Without having much code to go on, this is what I've cooked up.

You can have a separate `Dictionary` of tempo changes that correspond to the index of the `lvlArray1`. And you can check that dictionary whenever you're about to create a new note.

Example:

```
var tempoChanges:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
tempoChanges[39] = 6; // specify a tempo change to 6 for the 40th note (index 39)

// check to see if there's a tempo change for index i
if(tempoChanges[i] != undefined)
{
    // if there is, change the tempo to that value
    sTempo = tempoChanges[i];
}
```